# Page Won't Overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow

Ok, this is a really dumb question, but I cannot get it to work. I want one part of the page to be 20%, and the other side to be 100%, a total width being 120%. Now, I'm doing all this to experiment with jQuery and a navbar, but I cannot for the life of me get these divs to overflow, so that there is a scroll bar on the bottom. All that happens is the 100% div goes below the 20% div. I have tried floats, but those aren't working and I don't know why. Thank you for any help

***CODE***

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

#allContainer {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#navbarDiv {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

#mainPageDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}

p {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="allContainer">
   <div id="navbarDiv">
    <p>
     LLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean a mauris et nulla facilisis eleifend. Sed metus orci, vulputate sit amet malesuada id, luctus vestibulum lacus. Sed faucibus, nibh vel faucibus porta, lectus lacus suscipit metus, ut posuere nulla dolor porttitor erat. Nam iaculis dolor et est tristique scelerisque. Integer gravida scelerisque est, ut pellentesque sem facilisis in. Quisque felis elit, laoreet id sagittis non, sollicitudin vitae turpis. Pellentesque quis quam sed nibh sollicitudin porttitor non ac sapien. Cras luctus egestas urna, vitae bibendum enim malesuada ut. Nulla porta tempus mi vel consequat. Aenean scelerisque porttitor felis, id elementum erat porttitor eu. Mauris vitae elit non lorem malesuada viverra non ac eros.
    </p>
   </div>
   <div id="mainPageDiv">
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean a mauris et nulla facilisis eleifend. Sed metus orci, vulputate sit amet malesuada id, luctus vestibulum lacus. Sed faucibus, nibh vel faucibus porta, lectus lacus suscipit metus, ut posuere nulla dolor porttitor erat. Nam iaculis dolor et est tristique scelerisque. Integer gravida scelerisque est, ut pellentesque sem facilisis in. Quisque felis elit, laoreet id sagittis non, sollicitudin vitae turpis. Pellentesque quis quam sed nibh sollicitudin porttitor non ac sapien. Cras luctus egestas urna, vitae bibendum enim malesuada ut. Nulla porta tempus mi vel consequat. Aenean scelerisque porttitor felis, id elementum erat porttitor eu. Mauris vitae elit non lorem malesuada viverra non ac eros.
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The natural behavior of block elements (the default display property of `<div>` and `<p>` tags is to go below previous content if there isn't enough room for it. Therefore, all you have to do is put the blocks into a container that has 120% width.

Fiddle: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/d89ascrz/1/)

**CSS**

```
#allContainer {
    background: green;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}
#navbarDiv {
    height: 100%;
    width: 16.666666%;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 50;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
}
#mainPageDiv {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function showNav() {
    $("#navbarDiv").show();
    $("#mainPageDiv").width("83.3333%");
    $("#allContainer").width("120%");
}
showNav();
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="allContainer">
    <div id="navbarDiv">
        <p>LLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
    </div>
    <div id="mainPageDiv">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: also, I don't always want the width to be 120%, cause the navbar isnt going to always be there, thats the jquery part, thats why i'm trying to get these divs to overflow

Comment: What do you mean by overflow exactly?

Comment: Like go off the page. And the new edit, almost works, but it's on the right rather than the left

Comment: Alright, I think I know what you want. If you are using jQuery to hide and show this nav, I'm also going to use it to update the css as well.